# A multi-variant integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $S$ be the solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded from below by the surface $z = x^2 + 2y^2$ and from above by the plane $z = 2x + 6y + 1$. Find the volume of $S$.

First of all, by equating the two equations, I get a ellipse. I have tried to directly integrate the volume over the ellipse. But it is complicated. I am wondering, is there any good way to do substitution? So that after changing variables, the integration becomes easier.

Comment: This question will be closed unless you specify what you've tried. Saying it's "urgent" is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Math.SE.  I hope you get a lot of our site.  One thing: telling us your problem is "urgent" isn't likely to motivate people; in fact, it will have the opposite effect.

Comment: Indeed: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/can-we-ban-the-use-of-urgent

Comment: Don't you mean "bounded from *below* by the surface $z=x^2+2y^2$   and from *above* by the plane $z=2x+6y+1$"?